# Ember.js Components - param is not passed in action inside a component

Tags: ember.js, components

**What I'm trying to do:**
Author can delete own post.

**Problem:**
It seems parameter `param=this` is not passed inside components:
I implemented a action `removePost` in `app/components/post-box.js` 
which triggers `item.deleteRecord()` but this `item` is `undefined` when I click delete button. Please help me.

**posts.hbs -> post-box.hbs -> post-box.js**

**app/templates/posts.hbs**

```
<div class="postsContainer">
  <div class="innerPostsContent">
    {{#each itemController="post"}}
      {{!-- Here is the problem: with components, param doesn't get this --}}
      {{post-box　user=user body=body date=date isAuthor=isAuthor view=view action="removePost" param=this session=session}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</div>
```

**app/templates/components/post-box.hbs**

```
<div class="eachPost">
  <div class="eachPostContent" {{action 'showDelete'}}>
    <p class="postAuthor"><strong>{{user.id}}</strong></p>
    <p class="postContent">{{body}}</p>
    <span class="timePosted"><em>{{format-date date}}</em></span>
      {{#if isAuthor}}   
        {{!-- this part leads next file: app/components/post-box.js --}}
        <a class="deletePost" {{action "removePost" this}}>Delete</a> 
      {{/if}}
  </div>
  {{/view}}
</div>
```

**app/components/post-box.js**

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    removePost: function(item) {
      if(this.get('session.user') && item.get('user') === this.get('session.user')){
        item.deleteRecord(); // Error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function 
        item.save();
      } else {
        console.log("You are not this post's author");
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using `controller.model` instead of this when passing the current context in, but beside that, its name inside the component is `param` not this, so you should be using

```
<a class="deletePost" {{action "removePost" param}}>Delete</a>
```

Comment: Ah that was my easy mistake, thanks! You are always so helpful! I'll use controller!

Comment: Although I moved the method `removePost` inside actions{} in PostsController. Now it doesn't trigger any error nor actions. hmm...

Comment: if you move `removePost` to the posts controller you'll need to send the action out of the component, so you'll still need an action inside of your component, called `removePost`, inside which you'll need to call `this.sendAction('action')` from that method.

Comment: Oh thanks! I tried like this with sending the parameter `this.get('this')` in `sendAction()`, but `item.deleteRecord` part returns `unidentified is not a function`, but here, on console when I typed `item` it returns the correct object and `item.get('body')` it correctly returns the post's body. So somehow `item.deleteRecord()` is not working.

Comment: it's because it's the controller, not the record.  the controller itself will proxy properties to and from the model, but it won't proxy function calls (deleteRecord).  Try sending in `controller.model` instead of just controller, or you can just do `item.get('model').deleteRecord()`

Comment: Thanks! I'm sorry I don't know what `controller.model` is but is it like setupControlelr in route like `setupController: function(controller, model) { controller.set('model', model);}` ? I'm looking for it in docs now.

Comment: sorry, I meant when you created your component, `{{post-box　user=user body=body date=date isAuthor=isAuthor view=view action="removePost" param=controller.model session=session}}`

Comment: The controller is just a decorator over the model, which proxies properties to and from the model.  And this covers most use cases available from the template, but within code, if you need to run a function from the model, you can't run it against the controller, it must be on the model.  For example, if a controller is decorating a model (`controller.set('model', model)`), `controller.get('foo')` should return the same thing as `model.get('foo')`, but `controller.someFunc()` is different than `model.someFunc()`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I think I understood it better now! and I will read more docs, thank you for your help!